# MySQL Statement with question mark and colon

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to decipher a particular statement that is in PHP program that is doing a Mysql query.  The query has ?: and ? in it.  What is there function?

```
$data = db_get_field("SELECT data FROM ?:order_data WHERE order_id = ?i AND type = 'A'", $order_id);
```

Thanks for any help.

Chris

Comment: `db_get_field` is not a built-in function. Find the definition.

Comment: license is paid for.  just being curious what the ?: was for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like placeholders for prepared statements. You provide the `?` where you will later provide an actual value. Consider this example from the PHP documentation:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Your particular example appears to be from [CS-Cart](http://docs.cs-cart.com/database-standards). For instance, according to their documentation `?i` forces the value passed into that placeholder to be converted to an integer (this is similar to the way [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) works).

```
$number = 9;
echo sprintf( "I have %d tasks.", $number );
// Outputs "I have 9 tasks."
```

In the above case, `$number` is treated as an integer. If I tried to pass a string into that slot, I'd get very different results:

```
$number = "completed";
echo sprintf( "I have %d tasks.", $number );
// Outputs "I have 0 tasks."
```

Note here how my types didn't match up, and therefore `0` replaced `completed` in the output.

Bottom line, these are placeholders.

Comment: it's weird, though `?` is an anonymous placeholder, and `:order_data` could be a named one. I've never seen the two mixed like that in a query.

Comment: @MarcB According to [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98715), mixing both is not supported. I think the OPs code has something else going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The characters `?` are `:` identifiers to form a parametrized queries. Later you bind values to variables and the engine performs the query for multiple values. This works faster, as the query is compiled once by server rather than compiling it for each variable=value set.